# Kazam Recorded Audio is distorted

Tags: audio-recording, kazam

Every time I record my screen, and PC audio, the audio is always distorted. It will sound deeper and slower than it did when it was playing live. The issue is that this is a sudden problem, only starting just a few days ago. For months it recorded audio just fine and I'm at a loss to explain this or think of a fix.

Does anyone have any ideas? Or does anyone know where I can start looking for answers?

Here is the output of `pulseaudio --dump-conf`:

```
### Read from configuration file: /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ###
daemonize = no
fail = yes
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 5
allow-module-loading = yes
allow-exit = yes
use-pid-file = yes
system-instance = no
local-server-type = user
cpu-limit = no
enable-shm = yes
flat-volumes = no
lock-memory = no
exit-idle-time = 20
scache-idle-time = 20
dl-search-path = /usr/lib/pulse-4.0/modules
default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-default-script-file = yes
log-target = auto
log-level = notice
resample-method = speex-float-1
enable-remixing = yes
enable-lfe-remixing = no
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 44100
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
default-fragments = 8
default-fragment-size-msec = 10
enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
shm-size-bytes = 0
log-meta = no
log-time = no
log-backtrace = 0
rlimit-fsize = -1
rlimit-data = -1
rlimit-stack = -1
rlimit-core = -1
rlimit-rss = -1
rlimit-as = -1
rlimit-nproc = -1
rlimit-nofile = 256
rlimit-memlock = -1
rlimit-locks = -1
rlimit-sigpending = -1
rlimit-msgqueue = -1
rlimit-nice = 31
rlimit-rtprio = 9
rlimit-rttime = 1000000
```

Here is the stream date from the file:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Kazam_screencast_00000.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomiso2
    creation_time   : 2017-12-20T05:45:26.000000Z
    encoder         : x264
  Duration: 00:00:11.91, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3402 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3289 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 2500 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-12-20T05:45:26.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 115 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-12-20T05:45:26.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Comment: recent updates this week? If no software's changed, maybe some hardware's failing

Comment: Check your pulseaudio sample rate by running `pulseaudio --dump-conf`. Check your avi files sample rate by running `ffmpeg -i /path/to/file`. Then check if there is a different rate set in `kazam`. [edit] your question to include the results from the above commands.

Comment: Thanks _J. Starnes_. I will edit the information in when I get home.

Comment: I'm not seeing any issue in the output of the commands. I have installed `kazam`. `vlc` had no issue playing back the screen casts that I made. What are you using to play the files back?

Comment: I am using VLC. I have always used VLC, and the files that recorded fine a few days ago still play fine in VLC. The issue has me completely stumped. I hate to wipe away my OS and reinstall, but at this point I don't know what else to do.

Comment: short of reinstalling the os try purging `kazam`. `sudo apt-get purge kazam` and the `sudo apt-get install kazam`

Comment: Actually , I have an update. I just changed the settings to record from the microphone and that worked flawlessly. I then changed the settings back to record from speakers and it is now recording perfectly well again... so... take that as you will. I don't consider the issue resolved because I have no idea what happened and I have no idea if it'll go back to the distorted way it was, but for now it's at least working as I would like it to again.